# What is the default JAX-RS behavior with web.xml-configured authentication and the absence of security annotations?

Tags: jax-rs, jersey-2.0

I am working with Payara Micro 174 if it matters (which uses Jersey 2.25.1 for its JAX-RS implementation).

I have a JAX-RS application.

I have written, and successfully hooked up, a web-app-specific dummy JASPIC authenticator, which runs fine, and identifies any user as `fred` and as belonging to the group `fred`.  I have a role-to-principal binding set up in my glassfish-web.xml so that anyone who is in the group `fred` is assigned the role `fred`.

I have no security-related annotations on my resource classes (e.g. no `@RolesAllowed`, no `@DenyAll`, no `@PermitAll`).

If I authenticate against this application, I can see my JASPIC authenticator run, and return success.  This tells me that as far as Payara is concerned, authentication was successful, so in some abstract way I would presume that there is now a `Principal` set up bound to the role `fred`.

But my request is rejected with a `403`.

This tells me that unannotated resource classes must effectively default to `@DenyAll`.  Is this in fact true, or am I observing some fault in my setup?

Comment: Works fine for me, both with and without the vendor-specific group-to-role mapping. Note that I tested without declaring anything security-relevant in `web.xml`, and registered the `ServerAuthModule` in the usual programmatic fashion (custom `AuthConfigProvider` + `ServletContextListener`). As for the default behavior, it should be `@PermitAll`-equivalent, according to the Servlet spec (IIRC, JAX-RS is silent on this).